# sum adjacent columns for each column in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, diff

I am trying to get a function that is the opposite of diff()
I want to add the values of adjacent columns in a matrix for each column in the matrix.
I do NOT need the sum of the entire column or row.
For example:

If I had:

```
[ 1  2  4;
  3  5  8 ]
```

I would end up with:

```
[ 3  6;
  8  13 ]
```

Of course for just one or two columns this is simple as I can just do x[,1]+x[,2], but these matrices are quite large.

I'm surprised that I cannot seem to find an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

```
m <- matrix(c(1,3,2,5,4,8), nrow=2)
m[,-1] + m[,-ncol(m)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
[2,]    8   13
```

Or, just for the fun of it:

```
n <- ncol(m)
x <- suppressWarnings(matrix(c(1, 1, rep(0, n-1)), 
                             nrow = n, ncol = n-1))
m %*% x

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
[2,]    8   13
```

Comment: Very nice, tried it on a slightly larger matrix and works well there too, `m <- matrix(rpois(110, 3), nrow=11)` +1

Answer (score 2):

Dummy data

```
mat <- matrix(sample(0:9, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
```

Solution:

```
sum.mat <- lapply(1:(ncol(mat)-1), function(i) mat[,i] + mat[,i+1])
sum.mat <- matrix(unlist(sum.mat), byrow = FALSE, nrow = nrow(mat))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,4,3,5,8), nrow=2, byrow=T)
sapply(2:ncol(m), function(x) m[,x] + m[,(x-1)])
```